# making a usb device from scratch... what are the pros of a VCP driver?

Tags: usb, device-driver

I'm building a thingy that will have a usb interface, I'm pretty keen on the FT232RL for this purpose. The manufacturers offer virtual com port drivers for linux and windows. I haven't really done this sort of thing before so I was wondering if anybody can tell me why one might want to use a VCP driver or point me in the direction of some resources on the topic. I'm assuming it's just for the sake of simplifying the process of writing a driver but i'm really not certain right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, VCP stands for "Virtual COM Port".  If you use the drivers from FTDI, they will create a virtual COM port on your computer when you plug in the device.  Nearly every language has a library for sending and receiving bytes on COM ports (e.g. [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)), so your device will be usable from all of those languages.  You will not have to write a driver.